# Creating a chart based on drop down selection?

Tags: google-sheets

I've seen quite a few tutorials on how to create a drop down selection from a table, then turn it into a chart. I'm having the trouble of creating a chart from a specific drop down selection IN my table. for example. I only want to show the  data in my chart based on the "salary" selection. NOT any income gained from my house mate. see below.
[image]

under "category" I have 6 selections to choose from but want to plot a line chart specifically to data under "salary"

Answer (score 1):

if anyone else has trouble working it out...

```
=FILTER(G5:J30, J5:J30 = "salary")
```

this puts the data into its own table discarding the rest. You can either put this in a separate sheet or if you're a neat freak like me use conditional formatting make the text white (or whatever your background color is) and hide it somewhere at the bottom of your spreadsheet. from there you can simply make a chart out of it